# scrollController inconsistent maxScrollExtent calc item height

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverList` and a `SliverAppBar` in it.
The list is populated with a stream that loads rows. and a certain point the list reaches its full length.
All of the items are of equal size, but it may change (based on actions in other pages of the app).
I'm trying to save the index of the tile that the user has pressed on. And later, when the user opens the list again, scroll to this index.
To do so, I'm saving the index and calculating items size by dividing `macScrollExtent` in the length of the list.
The problem is that I get different results every time (I made sure the list is fully loaded) and hence can't scroll to the correct index.

```dart
CupertinoScrollbar(
  controller: scrollController,
  child: CustomScrollView(
    controller: scrollController,
    slivers: <Widget>[
      appBar,
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (c, i) {
            if (dividerBuilder == null) return itemBuilder(c, i);
            if (i.isOdd) return dividerBuilder(c, i ~/ 2);
            return itemBuilder(c, i ~/ 2);
          },
          childCount: _childCount,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Why isn't maxScrollExtent constant?
Are there other ways to scroll to a certain index\calculate an item's height?